# Import Routes from routes.js is crashing my nodemon server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, nodemon

while importing Routes from routes.js nodemon crash is there any new update regarding the importation of Routes from routes.js??

Index.js code

```
import express from "express";

//components
import Connection from "./database/db.js";
import Routes from "./routes/Route.js";

const app = express();
app.use("/", Routes);

const PORT = 8000;

Connection();
app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(`Server is running successfully on PORT ${PORT}`)
);
```

Routes.js code

```
import express from "express";

import {
  newConversation,
  getConversation,
} from "../controller/conversation-controller.js";
import { addUser, getUser } from "../controller/user-controller.js";
import { newMessage, getMessage } from "../controller/message-controller.js";

const route = express.Router();

route.post("/add", addUser);
route.get("/users", getUser);

route.post("/conversation/add", newConversation);
route.post("/conversation/get", getConversation);

route.post("/message/add", newMessage);
route.get("/message/get/:id", getMessage);

export default route;
```

Comment: Can you add the error? Does it work when you run it using node app name?

Comment: You should `import route from "./routes/Route.js";`

Comment: nodemon is crashing while importing Routes from './routes/Routes.js' that's the error